# Get 415 error while calling computer vision OCR

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services

I am using Azure computer vision API. I can post an image url to Azure and get its result successfully by nodejs.

However when I want to post a local image instead of an image url , I always get 415 error. So did I miss something?

Thanks in advance .

Comment: Could you add some more details? How are you currently sending the local image and which headers are you using. What are the image dimensions, file size and image format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to post a local image to Azure computer version OCR using nodejs. just try the code below :

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const fs  = require('fs');


let subscriptionKey = '<your subscription key>';
let endpoint = '<your computer vision endpoint>';
let filePath = "<path of your local image>";
const base64 =  fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'base64')
const data = Buffer.from(base64, 'base64')

var uriBase = endpoint + "vision/v2.1/ocr";

fetch(uriBase ,
{
method: 'POST',
headers: 
    {
    'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
    },
body: data,
}).then((response) => response.json()).then((data) =>
{
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
}).catch((error) =>
{
console.log(error);
});
```

As far as I know if you use `multipart/form-data`, will cause 415 error .

Result :

[image]